# Styles in external stylesheet do not work. Maybe the website doesn't load the stylesheet. But why?

Tags: html, css

I am working on my client's [website](http://www.planilux.com).

I've included `hacks.css` in the header, but the website does not apply the styles from it.

Please help me out?

(`hacks.css` is a style-sheet with `margin` and `padding` styling. )

Comment: Some divs got some classes from hacks.css. It is all about margins and paddings

Comment: describe where you are getting points so we can look at that as we don't know what is structure of your site so.

Comment: It applies the styles. Have you a specific example where an element has not the CSS rules from hacks.css ?

Comment: Also, note that there is some "errors" in your CSS : .mbot50,
.mbottom40 {margin-bottom: 50px;} (I think you mean .mbot50,
.mbottom50 {margin-bottom: 50px;}, but right now, .mbottom50 doesn't exist, but you use it on your html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I think some classes you use are not defined in your CSS file**. For example , you use .mbottom50 class in your HTML but in the CSS:

```
 .mbot50, .mbottom40 {margin-bottom: 50px;} // no .mbottom50 class here
```

So yeah, class that have no CSS rules can't make the job :)

Answer (score 3):

`hack.css` is taking effect, you just need to make sure you apply it the right way and it does not conflict with any styling you may apply (check the dev tools):

[image: check the dev tools]

**Some tips :**

Load the `hack.css` before your style CSS and use `!important` in your style

`.yourdiv{margin: 2%!important}`

for overriding hack margins if you really have to use a hack class on your element with another custom class.

Or simply use your own class (without adding hack class) and apply your margins when you need customization.

Comment: Hey, thanks, but this does not help me anyway. I'm not that familiar with the dev-tools, that is why i am asking here.

Comment: @Leothelion Edited the answer to become an answer

Comment: @injuvik you shall be more specific then with your question or you shall get familiar with dev tools. I have added some notes to the answers hope they are useful and if not elaborate your question please.

Comment: Well, do not use !important if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error at your hacks.css

```
.mbot40,
.mbottom40 {margin-bottom: 40px;)
.mbot30,
.mbottom30 {margin-bottom: 30px;)
```

should be

```
.mbot40,
.mbottom40 {margin-bottom: 40px;}
.mbot30,
.mbottom30 {margin-bottom: 30px;}
```

Curly brackets should be used instead! ( **}** ). That's why it skips the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the bug by myself: I've had some normal brackets in my stylesheet, instead of proper curly brackets:

```
.mbottom30 {margin-bottom: 30px;) <--- wrong

.mbottom30 {margin-bottom: 30px;} <--- right
```

Now all is well! Thank you all!

Comment: I've actually posted your kind of bug in your hacks.css before you, but that's fine if you've found it yourself ;)